# Search a list of words within a string and return matching word

Tags: python, python-3.x

Edit:
@rong @shaik moeed
Here is a code that generates part of the data frame and the problem I am facing:

```
temp = [[1, 'blblblblblb. The quaity of research was good. blblblblb'],
        [2, 'blblblblblb. The quaity of research was average. blblblblb'],
        [3, 'blblblblblb. The quaity of research was poor. blblblblb'],
        [4, 'blblblblblb. The quaity of research was good. blblblblb']
        ]
Data = pd.DataFrame(temp,columns=['ID','Report'])
Data['Sentence']=Data['Report'].str.extract(r"([^.]*?The quaity of research was [^.]*\.)")

Quality_dic=dict([(1, 'excellent'), (2, 'good'),  (3, 'average') , (4, 'poor'), (5, 'unassessable')])



Data['Quality']=[k for k,v in Quality_dic.items() if v in  Data['Sentence'].str.split()]
```

The solutions suggested still unfortunately dont work.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?
Thank you everyone for your time and input

Comment: You don't need `.apply` here and you most likely don't need `re.findall`... what does `df['REPORT'].str.extract(r'(?i)the quality of the research was (.*?)\b')` give you?

Comment: Thanks @JonClements . Your code returned an empty string. The first part of the code df['REPORT'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"([^.]*?the quality of the research was[^.]*\.)" ,x, flags=re.I)) works fine, it is the last part matching the  dictionary to the content is the problem

Comment: It may (appear to) work fine... but it's nasty and is definitely going to trip you up later... could you provide a sample of `df['REPORT'].head(10)` or something - that way someone can actually work with example data and make suitable suggestions...

Comment: I think you might be right, I have now changed according to your suggestion with a minor edit: df['Sentence']=df['REPOR'].str.extract(r"([^.]*?the quality of the research was[^.]*\.)")

Comment: I am however still not able to match it to the dictionary items despite having a "cleaner" extract using your method

Comment: Well.. if you would be kind enough to provide some sample data, you can be shown how to do that...

Comment: I am trying but not sure how. I am using pycharm and using head() only prints the first maybe 20 characters of the string

Comment: Can you do `df['REPORT'].head(10).tolist()` and [edit] your post with the result of that in a codeblock?

Comment: I have edited the post now, any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a df as your data and implemented completely as you required.

In `Quality_dic`, you have same key for `Good` and `Unassessable`. So `Good` will override with `Unassessable`.

Try now,

```
>>> temp = [[1, 'blblblblblb. The quaity of research was good. blblblblb'],
        [2, 'blblblblblb. The quaity of research was average. blblblblb'],
        [3, 'blblblblblb. The quaity of research was poor. blblblblb'],
        [4, 'blblblblblb. The quaity of research was good. blblblblb']
        ]

>>> Data = pd.DataFrame(temp,columns=['ID','Report'])

>>> Data['Sentence']=Data['Report'].str.extract(r"([^.]*?The quaity of research was [^.]*\.)")

>>> index_col = []

>>> for index, row in Data.iterrows():
        index_col.append([k for k,v in Quality_dic.items() if v.lower() in  row['Sentence'].replace('.','').split()][0])
>>> Data["index_col"]=index_col
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> Data

   ID    ...    index_col
0   1    ...            2
1   2    ...            3
2   3    ...            4
3   4    ...            2

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

**Note:**

```
... - means columns are hiding as there is no space to display.
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, this returned an error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: hmmmm. Not sure what is happening now, a different error:     ValueError('Length of values does not match length of index')
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: That is due to no word is matching. It means the format of words in your final sentence and  values in dictionary are not same.

Comment: It is the same i promise! However, I am wondering if using re.findall is causing a problem as it might be returning a list and the string method would not work on it?

Comment: I have updated the code to extract string: df['Sentence']=df['REPOR'].str.extract(r"([^.]*?the quality of the research was[^.]*\.)") but using your code df['Quality']=[k for k,v in Quality_dic.items() if v in  df['Scentence'].str.split()]  still generates the error

Comment: I have edited the post now, any suggestions please?

Comment: @user11484278 Answer was updated. Please check now. If it solve your issue, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I just copied all your code, still generates an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Your `Quality_dic` has `bowel` instead of `good`. Change and check

Comment: Did notice that actually, and changed to Quality_dic=dict([(1, 'excellent'), (2, 'good'),  (3, 'average') , (4, 'poor'), (5, 'unassessable')]) still the same problem. I really appreciate your help solving this...

Comment: `for loop` was updated according to your current `Quality_dic`. Check now

Comment: Worked finally! Thank you so much

Comment: Actually, your `Quality_dic` was changing time to time. So, the solution needed to update so many times. Wish you a happy coding. All these things are common for a coder ;-).

Answer (score 0):

```
quality_dic = dict([(1, 'Excellent'), (2, 'Good'), (3, 'Average') , (4, 'Poor'), (2, 'Unassessable')])

sentence = 'The quality of the research was Poor' # note that 'Poor' here is capitalized

for rating in quality_dic:
    if quality_dic[rating] in sentence:
        print(quality_dic[rating]) # df['Quality'] = quality_dic[rating]

# or if you want a one-liner:
df['Quality'] = [quality_dic[rating] in sentence for rating in quality_dic]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, didnt really work.  The sentence is a column now in a dataframe.

Comment: TypeError: 'StringMethods' object is not callable

Comment: @user11484278 does your column row in the dataframe contain a string? `sentence` here is just a string (also your question is regarding a string - that's how I would "search a list of words within a string and return matching word"). Try replacing the variable `sentence` in my example with df['sentence']` (or `Scentence`  if you prefer). Also might be worth updating your question with example columns/rows =)

Comment: I have edited the post now, any suggestions please?